# Faut-il mettre la marque du pluriel quand on utilise « on » à la place de « nous »?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, pluriel

En utilisant « on » à la place de « nous », comme dans « on est allés à la plage » pour « nous sommes allés à la plage », faut-il mettre la marque du pluriel et écrire *allé**s*** même si « on » est la troisième personne du singulier ?

J'ai tendance à faire ainsi car dans ce cas « on » a un sens de pluriel, mais je sais que plusieurs personnes de mon entourage trouvent ça bizarre et préfèrent écrire « on est allé »…

Y a-t-il une règle grammaticale à ce sujet ? Est-ce qu'écrire « on est allés » est possible, recommandé, déconseillé, ou tout simplement faux ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Voir [le dictionnaire de l'Académie](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/on)

> L'adjectif attribut se rapportant à On s'accorde au masculin singulier. Il arrive toutefois que l'accord se fasse, par syllepse, avec le sens, lorsque On renvoie à un sujet dont on connaît le genre et le nombre. Comme on est contents de se retrouver si nombreux !

Answer (score 10):

La [Banque de dépannage linguistique](http://66.46.185.79/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=1708) de l'Office québécois de la langue française consacre également l'accord en genre et en nombre de *on* lorsqu'il réfère à un groupe de personnes identifiées :

> Le pronom on peut aussi représenter une ou plusieurs personnes qui sont bien identifiées. On peut alors le remplacer par un pronom personnel (je, tu, nous, vous). Dans ces emplois, le participe passé ou l’adjectif qui s’y rapporte prend le genre et le nombre du sujet représenté par on.

Cependant :

> L’emploi de on pour désigner une ou plusieurs personnes bien définies est fréquent à l’oral. Toutefois, à l’écrit et dans un style soutenu, il est préférable d’utiliser le pronom personnel, le plus souvent nous, correspondant.

Comment: Je ne connaissais pas ce site, merci pour le lien !

Answer (score 3):

Quand le genre ou le nombre grammatical ne correspond pas au genre ou au nombre logique, la théorie voudrait accorder suivant la grammaire.  En pratique, plus on est éloigné du mot imposant le genre ou le nombre grammatical, plus souvent on passe au genre ou au nombre logique.

Dans « on est allé », je n'hésite pas, les mots sont trop proches pour faire violence à la grammaire.

Answer (score -6):

"On", pronom indéfini singulier (étymologiquement : homme, en général), n'a rien de commun avec nous, pronom personnel.

Quand il fait chaud, on aime aller à la plage.

A la Renaissance et au prétendu Siècle des lumières, on est **allé** jusqu'à brûler des sorcières par milliers, ce qui était rarissime antérieurement. (vérités générales).

Albert, Bertrand, Claudine, et moi, nous sommes **allés** sur la plage. (personnes désignées, événement ponctuel).

*"On est allé se promener"* n'a pas de sens.

Comment: On en pense ce que l’on veut, mais force est de constater que « on » est de nos jours fréquemment utilisé pour exprimer un « nous » et que « On est allés se promener » est parfaitement compris de tous les locuteurs.

Comment: Curieuse position, de prendre ce qui est compris comme acceptable, voire norme. "Moi y en a pas être content" serait parfaitement compris. Ne me soupçonnez surtout pas de racisme : c'est en Afrique Noire que j'ai lu et entendu le meilleur français ; j'ai même eu des étudiants Zaïrois qui se plaignaient de devoir désapprendre, une fois en métropole et pour ne pas se singulariser, qu'il faut l'imparfait du subjonctif après le conditionnel (règle très logique, naturelle, et conservée sans peine en espagnol).

Comment: Remarquez que j’ai bien précisé qu’il était également *utilisé* et non pas seulement compris. Si une phrase utilisée, comprise et, qui plus est, non reconnue comme fautive par les locuteurs n’est pas correcte, quels sont vos critères pour la reconnaître comme telle. Remarquons à toute fin utile que la quatorzième édition du Bon Usage propose des exemples de cette utilisation du « on » par, entre autres, Flaubert et Gide.

Comment: Entre les deux phrases suivantes, est-ce que vous n'avez pas une intuition claire de ce qui est correct pour l'interprétation qui caractérise les français dans leur ensemble : *en France, on est original* ou bien *en France, on est originaux*...